# How to get the unique Process ID from a 3rd party exe

Tags: vb.net, process

Ive created a screen recorder and stream recorder that can run at the same time. I'm using FFMPEG to perform the recordings which are triggered using the Process.Start() function. Now if both recording options are running, I have 2 FFMPEG programs running and 2 Console windows running. So, I need to be able to close or exit either recording options independently without it effecting the other.

So far this is my code...

```
    Dim cmdstr = "/k ffmpeg.exe -y -probesize 10M -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio=""" & 
    Audio_name & """ -acodec pcm_s16le -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -vcodec libx264 -qp 0 
    -threads 0 -crf 18 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency " & str & "\Recordings\ScreenRecorder" 
    & FileTime & ".mkv"


                If TestFF = True Then
                    MsgBox("1. Test Mode: " & cmdstr)
                    Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k ffmpeg.exe -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy") ' This lists all devices
                    Process.Start("cmd.exe", cmdstr)
                    RTBStreamData1.Text = cmdstr
                    RecordingInProcess = True
                    RecordingOn = True
                Else
                    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
                    startInfo.Arguments = cmdstr
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                    Process.Start(startInfo)
                    RecordingInProcess = True
                    RecordingOn = True
                    Dim ProcID As Integer = Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id
                    Label13.Text = ProcID.ToString
```

I am able to get the ID of the application itself, but it is the individual processes of ffmpeg and the associated console window that I need to be able to close at the same time.

any form of help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

In the image above you can see that i was able to track the first process, but not the second!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood: A trick you can use might be you pass a “FAKE” custom argument to each process you’re going to start by Process.Start(). After that looping running processes you can recognize your target process.
The code below gives an idea. (There is to change something in the SQL String in order to avoid SQL injection)

```
Dim PROCESS_CUSTOM_ARG As String = "UNIQUE_STRING_ID_HERE" '& _1  also add an integer incremental for each process

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    startInfo.Arguments = " - a lot of your Arguments here"
    startInfo.Arguments &= " - " & PROCESS_CUSTOM_ARG
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Process.Start(startInfo)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim searcher As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT ProcessId, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE '%" & PROCESS_CUSTOM_ARG & "' ")
    For Each p As System.Management.ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
        Dim ProcessId As String = p("ProcessId")
        Dim CommandLine As String = p("CommandLine")
        Console.WriteLine($"CommandLine: {CommandLine} ProcessId: {ProcessId}")
        Dim Proc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId)
        Proc.Kill()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there thank you for answering my question. I managed to get part of it to work. That is I was able to see the  extra argument on the windows command processor and I was able to see the Process ID. When I asked it to shut down, it did. But, I was not able to see the FFMPEG extra argument nor its PID. So it has remained running after exiting the recording. I followed your code but did not quite understand the "also add an integer incremental for each process
" comments. Could you expand on that. Thanks.

Comment: Just added an image above of the task manager displaying the process in action. I had to close each FFMPEG exe down individually. lol

Comment: @JohnHenderson You can track every process you are going to start even “ffmpeg.exe”. I see you are passing some arguments to that program like “ffmpeg.exe -y -probesize 10M ……… etc”, so just add on end of your cmdstr a Fake parameter (unique string id to be recognized after like the example above) . So , becomes  `cmdstr =  cmdstr & " -" & AN_UNIQUE_STRING_THAT_I_CAN_FIND_AFTER`

Comment: The integer after is some trick like UNIQUE_ID_1  to pass to one process,  UNIQUE_ID_2 to pass to another UNIQUE_ID_3 for another etc.
After with a loop you can find those by ID like for I = 0 to X →Dim FakeParam =  (“UNIQUE_ID” + I.ToString())  → find all my processes with that command parameter...

Comment: Note that you have to do this in every Process.Start call → Process.Start (“file.exe -param1 -param2 -param3” & MY_FAKE_PARAM)

Comment: thanks again I will give it a try, adding the extra command string, I just have to hope that FFMPEG does not try to read it or it will stop it functioning correctly. Everything you say makes plenty of sense. I will give it a go and let you know the out come. Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong happens with a fake parameter as inside of each application the parameters are searched explicitly by name. Your fake parameter  is something abstract for FFMPEG as it doesn’t that exists. Stay safe :)

Comment: Thanks G3nt_M3caj just to let you know that I gave your response to my question a very serious testing. Unfortunately FFMPEG would not accept the additional parameter at the end of the command string. I'm guessing thats just how FFMPEG works. I have figured out an alternative solution, but I am still finalising it. So thanks very much again.